# Projections and projective modules of $C(X)$

Tags: c-star-algebras, projective-module, topological-k-theory

This is a followup to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736756/what-are-the-projections-of-a-commutative-c-algebra) I made yesterday (disclaimer: I'm new here and I'm not sure if asking a new but related question is the correct procedure).

If $X$ is a connected, compact, Hausdorff space and $E$ is a one-dimensional vector bundle over $X$ then (according to Swan-Serre) the $C(X)$-module $C(X,E)$, of continuous sections of this bundle, is (isomorphic to) a projection of $C(X)$. So $C(E,X)$ is either trivial or isomorphic to $C(X)$. Now, it must be easy to find dim 1 bundles on many such $X$ that cannot have nonvanishing sections (like the Mobius strip) but that still have nontrivial sections, so that $C(X,E)$ is neither $C(X)$ nor trivial. Where is my error?

Comment: Your first claim is just wrong. Serre-Swan only tells you that you have a direct summand of a trivial bundle, but it says nothing about the rank of this bundle.

Comment: Oh, I was misled by a statement in the third paragraph of this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_K-theory

Is the statement (where $n$, the dimension of the bundle coincides with $n$ the C(X)-dimension of the free module where the projection is taken) wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. As you already observed, a nontrivial line bundle over a connected compact Hausdorff space $X$ is a counterexample.